# DMA cache coherent contiguous allocation

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I was looking at allocating a buffer for a DMA transaction. I read that there are two ways of doing this - coherent mappings or streaming mappings.

Now, we want cache coherent buffers. However, we are not doing any scatter/gather so we want the benefits of the `dma_map_single` call. We have set aside some contiguous memory in the bootargs so we always have enough contiguous memory available.

So I was wondering, can we call `dma_alloc_coherent` and then `dma_map_single` after it with the virtual address that `dma_alloc_coherent` returns? The returned physical address of the map single would then be set as the dma handle that `dma_alloc_coherent` returned in its call.

Does this make sense? Or is it superfluous/incorrect to do it this way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use both.  But you're also trying to solve a nonexistent problem.  Just use `dma_alloc_coherent()`, which gives you a contiguous DMA memory buffer with both virtual and physical addresses.  DMA to the physical address, access it from the CPU with the virtual address.  What's the issue?

Comment: Can I allocate large (8MB) chunks by using alloc_coherent? I allocate some memory using CMA=16MB in bootargs. Does alloc_coherent look for that memory allocated by the CMA bootarg? I thought that function call would do it for me but then I read [this](http://mina86.com/2012/06/10/deep-dive-into-contiguous-memory-allocator-part-i/). Around mid-article under subsection "DMA subsystem integration" it says we have to first make the alloc_coherent call look for the memory allocated by CMA at boot time. Is this necessary? [This](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel/1263136) doesn't do that.

Comment: Also, does dma_alloc_coherent() check to see if the dma handle was previously assigned? If I have a transmit buffer and a receive buffer, I would want them to be separate regions of contiguous memory. If I allocate a virtual/physical address for one buffer, would a second dma_alloc_coherent() call check first to make sure that it doesn't return a virtual/physical address within the previous buffer? I tried looking at the source code but I am having trouble finding the part that does this check. It should exist though right? Considering it is a very fundamental thing to do?

Comment: I read those pages.  CMA should be completely transparent.  It ensures that `dma_alloc_coherent()` will have access to a large amount of contiguous memory and that's it.  Re double-allocating... what?? Of course a properly working allocator will not hand you overlapping regions.  You're over-thinking this.  Just call  `dma_alloc_coherent()` for each region, and `dma_free_coherent()` when you're done, and move on.  If it gives you problems, come on back.

Comment: Alright thanks a lot. I was just making sure all cases were covered. We're new to kernel programming and have been stuck on this driver for almost a month now. Hopefully we'll get it working soon.

Again, thanks a lot for your answers.

Comment: @Peter, does dma_alloc_coherent returns contiguous memory ? I can't find such statement in DMA-API.txt. Thanks,

Comment: @ransh  maybe with IOMMU, it returns contiguous-looking physcial/virtual mem region both seen by CPU and device?